# Is trap inherited by a subshell?

Tags: shell, trap, subshell

I tried a following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo "touching a file" && touch $FILE' EXIT

foo1(){
        echo "foo1"
}
foo(){
        echo "foo"
        export FILE=${FILE:-/tmp/file1}
}
(foo1)
foo
```

The output for the above script was:

```
[root@usr1 my_tests]# ./test.sh
foo1
foo
touching a file
```

However I was expecting trap to be called on exit from `foo1` as well, which is called in a subshell.

- Is this expected?
- Is `trap` inherited by a subshell?
- If yes, then in what case is `trap` inherited by a subshell?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277090/standard-subshell-vs-command-substitution-subshell

Answer (score 17):

Trap handlers are never inherited by subshells. This is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/trap.html):

> When a subshell is entered, traps that are not being ignored are set to the default actions.

Note that ignored signals (`trap '' SIGFOO`) remain ignored in the subshell (and in external programs launched by the shell, too).

Comment: In bash you can `set -E` in order to have subshells inherit traps, but it is REALLY tricky to get right (at least in my experience).

Comment: I don't know if this works for all traps. I know it works for ERR

Comment: @dragon788 Re: "it is REALLY tricky to get right": can you please elaborate? If it is too long, then in a few words.

Comment: I see, the "that are not being ignored" part is important.

Answer (score 8):

`trap` is not propogated to subshells but some ways allow the subshell to report the traps of the parent shell and others don't. I did some tests on macos with bash.

#### GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0):

```
trap 'echo hello' EXIT
trap # trap -- 'echo hello' EXIT
echo "$(trap)" # trap -- 'echo hello' EXIT
trap | cat # trap -- 'echo hello' EXIT
(trap) | cat # trap -- 'echo hello' EXIT
cat < <(trap) # empty
cat <<< "$(trap)" # empty
bash -c 'trap' # empty
trap & # trap -- 'echo hello' EXIT
```

#### GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16):

```
trap 'echo hello' EXIT
trap # trap -- 'echo hello' EXIT
echo "$(trap)" # trap -- 'echo hello' EXIT
trap > >(cat) # trap -- 'echo hello' EXIT
trap | cat # empty
(trap) | cat # empty
cat < <(trap) # empty
cat <<< "$(trap)" # empty
bash -c 'trap' # empty
trap & # empty
```

This is good to know that `trap_output="$(trap)"` will work to capture trap output. I can't think of any other way to do it if that didn't work besides doing `trap >trap_output_file` to output it to a file (fifo won't work in `bash 3.2.57`) and then reading it back in with `trap_output="$(<trap_output_file)"`

fifo won't work in `bash 3.2.57` because `trap &` is empty for `bash 3.2.57` but not `bash 4.4.12`

#### GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0):

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo; trap >/tmp/fifo & trap_output=$(</tmp/fifo); rm -f /tmp/fifo; echo "$trap_output"
# trap -- 'echo hello' EXIT

mkfifo /tmp/fifo; trap_output=$(</tmp/fifo) & trap >/tmp/fifo; rm -f /tmp/fifo; echo "$trap_output"
# empty because trap_output=$(</tmp/fifo) sets the variable in a subshell
```

#### GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16):

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo; trap >/tmp/fifo & trap_output=$(</tmp/fifo); rm -f /tmp/fifo; echo "$trap_output"
# empty because trap >/tmp/fifo & is empty since it uses trap &

mkfifo /tmp/fifo; trap_output=$(</tmp/fifo) & trap >/tmp/fifo; rm -f /tmp/fifo; echo "$trap_output"
# empty because trap_output=$(</tmp/fifo) sets the variable in a subshell
```

Answer (score 0):

`trap` definitions are not propagated to sub-shells.

Verify by:

`trap "echo bla" 1 2 3`

`(trap)`

Comment: Many shells handle `(trap)` as a special case, so that the subshell can report (but not actually use) the traps of the parent shell.  So that test isn't always reliable.

Comment: It works with the Bourne Shell and it's derivates: `ksh88`, `bosh` (schily Bourne Shell) and `heirloom-sh`. You are correct: `ksh93` behaves differently.

Comment: It doesn't work in bash, which the script in question uses.

Comment: Well, it **works** in bash: `bash` does not output anything if you call `(trap)`.

Comment: @schily the example has an extra quote. Also, in my installation, both bash44 and bash 5+ report traps on `(trap)`

Comment: @usretc type fixed, thank you! BTW: this seems to be a ksh93 bug that has been copied. It does not apply to other shells -not even to ksh88.

Answer (score 0):

Although calling `trap` in a subshell shows the parent's traps, they are not executed in the subshell. You can set a new trap in the subshell.

To test this, create a script with the following code, run it and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
function sub { echo sub_before: `trap`; trap 'echo kill_sub; exit' SIGINT; echo sub_after: `trap`; while :; do sleep 1; done; }
function parent { echo parent_before: `trap`; trap 'pkill -2 -P $$; echo kill_parent; exit' SIGINT; echo parent_after: `trap`; sub & wait; }
parent
```

You'll see both traps being executed.

(bash 5.0.17)