# Bash: is it possible at all to trap SIGTERM (or other) in a subshell?

Tags: bash, subshell, trap

Consider multiple subshells, each writing its own log file. Consider that one subshell failed, leading to sending (using some mechanism) of `SIGTERM` to all the subshells. Upon reception of `SIGTERM` all the subshells are terminated. However, the `SIGTERM`-terminated subshell log files are kept. This is the problem.

Question: how to remove subshell log file after reception of `SIGTERM`?

I tried this:

```
_term()
{
  rm -f $log_file
}

trap _term SIGTERM
```

However, as I understand, this does not work because "[Trap handlers are never inherited by subshells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282887/334715)".

In the [description of `trap`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/trap.html) I see:

> When a subshell is entered, traps that are not being ignored are set to the default actions. This does not imply that the trap command cannot be used within the subshell to set new traps.

The last sentence is a bit confusing. Can someone explain is it possible *at all* to trap `SIGTERM` (or other) in a subshell?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are not inherited. But you can define a new trap in the subshell. And the parent shell has its own set of traps.

So then you send a signal to that parent shell, it can catch it and issue its own set of signals to subshells.

Here is a bunch of examples with explanations:
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/debugging.html#EX76